# How to make OAuth2 work for Azure Active Directory with multi-factor authentication on PHP

Tags: php, oauth, microsoft-graph-api

We are using OAuth 2.0 auth code grant on Azure Active Directory to authenticate the users in our web application with http://guzzlephp.org/

This has worked without problems, but now the AD maintenance wants to deploy a multi-factor authentication. Our current OAuth implementation is not in line with that.

Here is our code:

````
        $url = 'https://login.windows.net/' . $directoryIdAzure . '/oauth2/token'
            /** @var GuzzleHttp\Client $client **/
            $response = $client->post(
                $url,
                [
                    "headers" => [
                        "Accept" => "application/json"
                    ],
                    'form_params' => [
                        'resource'      => 'https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api',
                        'client_id'     => $clientIdAzure,
                        'client_secret' => $clientSecretAzure,
                        'grant_type'    => 'password',
                        'username'      => $user,
                        'password'      => $pass,
                        'scope'         => 'openid',
                    ]
                ]
            );``` 

Return this error:



error: 
 "error": "interaction_required",
    "error_description": "AADSTS50076: Due to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because you moved to a new location, you must use multi-factor authentication to access
````

Comment: Do not use the password grant type for authenticating users. I am surprised that Microsoft has not put your app on death row already. Azure AD does not support the password grant type + MFA.

Comment: If a change grant_type to "client_credentials" it's work, but don't get the Scopes of Power BI Service and return Client error: `GET https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response"

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft recommends you do not use the [ROPC flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc). In most scenarios, more secure alternatives are available and recommended. This flow requires a very high degree of trust in the application, and carries risks which are not present in other flows. You should only use this flow when other more secure flows can't be used.

Multi-factor authentication (MFA) is not supported with this OAuth 2.0 Resource Owner Password Credentials (ROPC) grant.